# Add an iOS 14 widget in project with compatibility with old iOS

Tags: ios, widget, ios14, xcode12, widgetkit

I want to add an iOS 14 widget in my existing project. But I get compile errors `is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer`. My widget target deployment target is set to iOS 14. Main app and the whole project deployment target is lower – 12.2. The application uses objective-c and Swift. I don't understand why I get this errors, when the widget deployment target corresponds to *iOS 14 or newer*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added @available(iOS 14, *) just before any respective struct or classes?
When creating files for the widget it includes target membership of the main target so you would have to add that on top of any structs or classes that are used for iOS 14 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.

In your widget files, make sure you check off your main project in the target membership, only check your widget Extension.